# ielm, bound to a certain buffer

Tags: interactive

Is there a way to run ielm, but with variables bound to a certain buffer?

I know about `M-:`, but having a shell like ielm to inspect things would be much easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hit `C-c C-b` to select a buffer for IELM to work upon.

Comment: Thanks. Almost what I want. How about point changing functions though? Is there a way to make them work? (end-of-buffer) for example.

Comment: Actually, the change is done which you can see by using `(progn (end-of-buffer) (point))`, however all changes are wrapped in a `save-excursion` block (among others) that reverts them afterwards.

Comment: Ah, OK, no way to get around then it seems, thanks. My main purpose is just to demo emacs command using ielm, to show how it affects the other buffer.

Comment: You're free to ask on the emacs-devel mailing list or report a bug to find out what exactly the rationale behind this is since commands that unintentionally move point usually restore it themselves using `save-excursion`. If your discussion leads somewhere, linking to it would be useful.